# Calling a python module from a .py file

Tags: python, python-module, autoencoder

I am a novice and I am trying to follow this code: https://github.com/llSourcell/autoencoder_demo/tree/master

Now, as you can see in the picture, the main file throws a no module found error. The question I have is how can I import the input_data found in the adjoint file?

[image]

Comment: probably because you didn't run the script from its path. Because of which it can't find the file

Comment: can you try opening cmd in the directory where the file is and then run the script?

Comment: you either have to be in the directory where it is, or add that directory to your path

Comment: Also, i think .. you directly opened the file from the zip. So, it's running from temporary folder. you can see this in the status and the bottom

Comment: It is the zip problem. I had not noted that the file is in zip format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to fix the problem.

Extract the files to some folder. Open a command prompt from that folder and then run the script. Make sure that you run cmd from the directory where files are. This is because, python looks at the current directory and Python path, when you try to import a module.